# Dropdown onchange doesnt work : React+ Typescript+ semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to bring up a dropdown using semantic-ui-react with typescript. The problem here I am facing is , I am unable to attach change handlers to it. It is throwing the following error *" Type 'SyntheticEvent' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent' "*.

```
//Importing Dropdown
import Dropdown from 'semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/modules/Dropdown';

//options array
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: 'Location 1', value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: 'Location 2', value: 2 },
  { key: 3, text: 'Location 3', value: 3 },
]

//state object
this.state ={
  value : ''
}

//Dropwdown change event
dropdownChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement> ,{value}) =>{
   this.setState({ value });
}

//Rendering Drop down
render()
{
  return(
      <Dropdown  
        options={opitons}
        name="value"  
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.dropdownChange}
      />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because the library is not using a `ChangeEvent` is using a `SyntheticEvent`

The typings for the `onChange` function on the `Dropdown` element are:

```js
onChange?: (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data: DropdownProps) => void
```

You can see them here https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.d.ts#L143

so you should change this line:

```
dropdownChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement> ,{value}) =>{
```

to:

```
dropdownChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement> ,{value}) =>{
```